# organic spectroscopy: n-phenethylacetamide base peak ion

Tags: organic-chemistry, mass-spectrometry

This is the n-phenethylacetamide mass spectrum [image]

[image]

His base peak ion is at 104 m/z. I have long been thinking about what its structure might be, but with a m/z ratio of 104 I can not think of anything plausible. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What ionisation method was used?

Comment: @Waylander With so much fragmentation it will have been electronic impact

Comment: Source Temperature: 200 °C, Sample Temperature: 150 °C, RESERVOIR: 75 eV

Comment: @Waylander Done! Long time since I did MS :-|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming electronic impact, the most electronegative atom will loose an electron and remain positively charged.
Amides typically undergo a McLafferty rearrangement.
In this case, the rearrangement can only be to one side, because the other chain is too short.

A neutral fragment of acetamide is lost (in its enolic form) and a positively charged styrene ion remains:

$\ce{C6H5-CH=CH2^+}$: $77+13+14=104$

The rearrangement is as follows:

[image]

(Sorry, I do not have a proper chemical drawing program with me; the arrows have been drawn on the touchscreen.)

Comment: That fits nicely

Comment: Well: so, is a styrene ion?